# Is ASP.NET Core EphemeralDataProtectionProvider useful for credential protection in memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, passwords, credentials, data-protection

I want to use ASP.NET Core DataProtection, `EphemeralDataProtectionProvider`, for protection of credentials in memory, to prevent passwords etc. from being leaked through memory dumps, swap files, or to be logged accidentally. Actual password is retrieved from web service; caching in memory to avoid call for every usage. The password shall not be persisted locally.

According to documentation, it's for testing or scripts, but it looks like a good option for memory caching. Is there any catch?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-ephemeral?view=aspnetcore-7.0

The applications are supposed to run on Alpine linux containers, currently still .NET 6.0, and locally on Windows for testing.

Security features to be implemented:

- Different *purposes* paths if different users/access rights exist in the application.

  - only unique service access in many cases.
- Passwords in char arrays instead of strings, overwrite immediately after use, through a `DisposableArray` and `using` blocks.
- To `SecureString` class where usable.

Known possible leaks (I know it's not 100% safe, but shall make attacks harder):

- dump/swap creation while password still in array.
- Basic `HttpClient` authentication requires string; immutable and lack of erasing (GC cleanup doesn't erase).

Currently for applications still having user-password credentials, but could be extended to other confidential data, too.

Comment: But where does this provider stores key with which it encrypts data? I guess in memory, in which case it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: As far as I know, at least for Windows ASP.NET Core DataProtection uses a machine key to derive from, by default. I'm not sure how this is implemented for Linux.

Comment: I mean you pass it some data to encrypt, and it encrypts that data with some key (doesn't matter how it was created). That key is present in memory of your process, so it will be present in memory dump. So it's just one additional step for attacher to decrypt it.